# Combining to MSSQL parameters SQL in one

Tags: sql-server

I work with MSSQL 2008 up.
I want to combine "more params" into the same select with diferent result
I cannot modifiy the query at runtime.
TABLE1 - CLIENTS ID_PK, NAME
TABLE2 - DETAILS ID_PK, IDCLIENT, DETAIL

Situation a
I need informations from all clients

```
SELECT C.IDCLIENT, C.NAME  
from CLIENTI C  
LEFT JOIN DETAILS D ON D.IDCLIENT = C.ID_PK
WHERE ... <where clause>
```

Situation b
I need informations from a specific IDCLIENT

```
SELECT C.IDCLIENT, C.NAME  
from CLIENTI C  
LEFT JOIN DETAILS D ON D.IDCLIENT = C.ID_PK  
WHERE C.ID_PK = :AID  
AND ...<where clause>
```

Situation c
I need informations from a range of clients (i pass this parameters as string)

```
SELECT C.IDCLIENT, C.NAME  
from CLIENTI C  
LEFT JOIN DETAILS D ON D.IDCLIENT = C.ID_PK  
WHERE C.ID_PK IN (:AID_STRING)  
AND ...<where clause>
```

how can i make this mix of params?
Razvan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this

```
SELECT C.IDCLIENT, C.NAME  
from CLIENTI C  
LEFT JOIN DETAILS D ON D.IDCLIENT = C.ID_PK
WHERE  (C.ID_PK = @AID or @AID is NULL)
... <where clause>
```

When you don't want `@AID` parameter just leave it as `NULL`

Comment: My SQL  
SELECT C.*, FCT.* 
FROM CLIENTI C
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT * FROM FCT_GETVANZARI(:ADATABEGIN, :ADATAEND)) AS FCT ON FCT.IDCLIENT = C.IDCLIENT
WHERE ((C.IDCLIENT = :AID) OR (:AISALL = 1) OR (C.IDCLIENT IN (SELECT OUTID FROM FCT_PARSESTRING(:AIDRANGE))))

ORDER BY C.NUME

where FCT_GETVANZARI is a function that select details between dates   and FCT_PARSESTRING is a function to create a dataset from a given comma delimited string like 1,2,3,4,5,6 (range ID of clients)